# Reports path not found or is not a directory-Jacoco+Maven+Jenkins+Sonar

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have followed below link to get code coverage for a multi module project.
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

Jenkins ver. 1.631
Sonar ver. 5.1.1
Jacoco ver. 0.7.9
Java ver. 1.8
Maven ver. 3.3.9

Main Pom file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <commons.lang.version>2.5</commons.lang.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
        <org.jboss.hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</org.jboss.hibernate.version>
        <jaxb.version>2.1</jaxb.version>
        <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
        <jersey.version>2.24.1</jersey.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
        <jackson.databind.version>2.8.1</jackson.databind.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.4</cxf.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.47</tomcat.version>
        <tomcat.port>18080</tomcat.port>
        <tomcat.client.port>28080</tomcat.client.port>
        <server.version>1.0.0</server.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <olingo.version>2.0.6</olingo.version>
        <felix.version>5.4.0</felix.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>5.1.13</version> <type>jar</type> <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
            <!-- 9.2-1002-jdbc4 -->
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.28</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.jboss.hibernate.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
        <version>${felix.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module3</module>
        <module>module4</module>
        <module>module5</module>
        <module>module6</module>
        <module>module7</module>
        <module>module8</module>
    </modules>


    <profiles>

        <!-- Default profile excludes connectors netsuite and salesforce in module1 
            and module2 and skips all module3 tests. -->
        <profile>
            <id>no-connector</id>

            <modules>
                <module>module1</module>
                <module>module2</module>
                <module>module3</module>
                <module>module4</module>
                <module>module5</module>
                <module>module6</module>
            </modules>

            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                                <excludedGroups>salesforce, netsuite, netsuitesso, GoogleDirectoryProvider,hybris4,hybris,hybris5, ftp</excludedGroups>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                                <excludedGroups>salesforce, netsuite, netsuitesso, netsuite_min, GoogleDirectoryProvider, hybris4, hybris, hybris5, ftp</excludedGroups>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.4</version> <configuration> <linkXref>true</linkXref> <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding> 
                <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens> <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk> <rulesets> 
                <ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset> <ruleset>/rulesets/imports.xml</ruleset> 
                <ruleset>/rulesets/unusedcode.xml</ruleset> <ruleset>/rulesets/controversial.xml</ruleset> 
                <ruleset>/rulesets/coupling.xml</ruleset> <ruleset>/rulesets/optimizations.xml</ruleset> 
                <ruleset>/rulesets/design.xml</ruleset> <ruleset>/rulesets/migrating.xml</ruleset> 
                <ruleset>/rulesets/typeresolution.xml</ruleset> </rulesets> </configuration> 
                </plugin> <plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.3.2</version> <configuration> <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput> 
                <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>target/site</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory> <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput> 
                </configuration> </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have added below plugin configuration in my Module1 and Module2 Pom xml where I have my Integration tests.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Maven Build Command-

```
-DargLine="-DDB_SERVER=localhost -DDB_PORT=1234 -DDB_NAME=test -DDB_USER=tester -DDB_PASSWORD=testerpwd -DDB_MAX_POOL=10" -Dcom.tester.redis=false clean verify
```

I am getting below error while I execute this using Jenkins.

```
[Checking] $ /Users/test-test/.jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonar_Runner/bin/sonar-runner -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://123.45.65/sonar?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 -Dsonar.jdbc.username=abcd -Dsonar.jdbc.password=abcd@123 -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://123.45.65:9000 ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectName=test-Test -Dsonar.projectVersion=28-06-2017-23 -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=reports/jacoco/jacoco-ut.exec -Dsonar.projectKey=test-Test -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=reports/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.modules=module1,module2,module3,module4,module5 -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking
SonarQube Runner 2.3
Java 1.8.0_60 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonar_Runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.1
18:16:25.065 INFO  - Load global repositories
18:16:25.337 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=283ms
18:16:25.339 INFO  - Server id: 20170616093959
18:16:25.344 INFO  - User cache: /Users/test-test/.sonar/cache
18:16:25.354 INFO  - Install plugins
18:16:27.168 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
18:16:27.187 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://172.26.72.76/sonar?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
18:16:28.882 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
18:16:30.622 WARN  - /!\ A multi-module project can't have source folders, so '/Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking' won't be used for the analysis. If you want to analyse files of this folder, you should create another sub-module and move them inside it.
18:16:31.095 INFO  - Load project repositories
18:16:31.323 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=228ms
18:16:31.323 INFO  - Load project settings
18:16:31.801 INFO  - Load technical debt model
18:16:31.852 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
18:16:34.302 WARN  - SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
18:16:34.304 INFO  - -------------  Scan module1
18:16:34.314 INFO  - Load module settings
18:16:34.707 INFO  - Load rules
18:16:35.242 INFO  - Base dir: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1
18:16:35.242 INFO  - Working dir: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/.sonar/test-Test_admin
18:16:35.242 INFO  - Source paths: .
18:16:35.243 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
18:16:35.243 INFO  - Index files
18:16:35.948 INFO  - 78 files indexed
18:16:39.945 INFO  - Quality profile for java: QPtest
18:16:40.081 INFO  - Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
18:16:40.113 INFO  - Didn't find which SCM provider is used. Fallback on configuration
18:16:40.113 WARN  - SCM URL must not be blank. SCM Stats Plugin will not run.Please check the parameter SCM URL or the <scm> section of Maven pom.
18:16:40.149 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor
18:16:40.456 INFO  - Configured Java source version: none
18:16:40.841 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
18:16:40.844 INFO  - 78 source files to be analyzed
18:16:50.845 INFO  - 13/78 files analyzed, current file: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1/src/main/java/com/test/services/impl/ApplicationService.java
18:17:00.849 INFO  - 25/78 files analyzed, current file: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1/src/main/java/com/test/services/impl/exampleServiceService.java
18:17:10.849 INFO  - 37/78 files analyzed, current file: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1/src/main/java/com/test/services/impl/StarterProject.java
18:17:20.851 INFO  - 74/78 files analyzed, current file: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1/src/main/java/com/test/test/client/ServiceProviderIT.java
18:17:21.904 INFO  - 78/78 source files have been analyzed
18:17:21.904 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 41063 ms
18:17:21.904 WARN  - Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer. The org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DependenciesVisitor@585fa2fb, org.sonar.java.checks.UnusedPrivateMethodCheck@2434f548, org.sonar.java.checks.UnusedProtectedMethodCheck@72bdb6d3, CycleBetweenPackages rule are disabled.
18:17:21.904 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
18:17:21.904 INFO  - 0 source files to be analyzed
18:17:21.904 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 0 ms
18:17:21.905 INFO  - 0/0 source files have been analyzed
18:17:21.905 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=41756ms
18:17:21.906 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
18:17:21.911 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=5ms
18:17:21.911 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
18:17:21.915 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=4ms
18:17:21.915 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
18:17:23.303 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=1388ms
18:17:23.303 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
18:17:23.339 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=36ms
18:17:23.339 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
18:17:23.420 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=81ms
18:17:23.420 INFO  - Sensor CoberturaSensor
18:17:23.420 WARN  - Cobertura report not found at /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
18:17:23.420 INFO  - Sensor CoberturaSensor (done) | time=0ms
18:17:23.420 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor@5bebff4b
18:17:23.451 WARN  - Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing sonar or check the location of compiled classes to make it possible for Findbugs to analyse your project.
18:17:23.451 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor@5bebff4b (done) | time=31ms
18:17:23.451 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
18:17:23.451 INFO  - parsing /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1/target/surefire-reports
18:17:23.451 ERROR - Reports path not found or is not a directory: /Users/test-test/.jenkins/test/test/Checking/module1/target/surefire-reports
```

My sonar.properties are as below-

```
sonar.projectKey=test-Test
sonar.projectName=test-Test
sonar.projectVersion=$PipelineId
sonar.modules=module1,module2,module3,module4,module5
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=reports/jacoco/jacoco-ut.exec
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=reports/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec
sonar.sources=.
```

Sonar IMG shows null as Unit Coverage.

[image]

How to include UT ans IT to get good no# of code coverage.

Comment: The current version is 6.4 and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're going to have a hard time finding help for versions before that.